# Smallest time-slice where OpenMP is useful

Tags: performance, openmp

I'm aware this will vary between systems and implementations, but I have absolutely no idea if OpenMP is feasible for use where you have easily parallelizable code that doesn't takea  long time to run. For instance if I have a loop which would be ideal for OpenMP, but only takes a couple of ms to run on a single thread, will the overhead kill any gains?

My usage is in real-time rendering, where we have perhaps 20ms to generate each frame. So typically we don't have any single block of code taking more than 5-10ms... is OpenMP targeted at this kind of time-scale, or only on operations taking several *seconds* to run?

Any anecdotal/empirical data is welcome, as well as more 'official' sources. I suppose I'm primarily interested in MSVC++ and GCC OpenMP implementations.

I found this interesting article: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/06/02/using-openmp-to-parallelize-a-game/

Comment: That is an interesting article.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, to all empirical questions when data is not available, is 42 ...

But seriously, you're going to have to derive your own answer to this question for your own configuration of hardware, software and problem.

Yes, perhaps when, in 1997, OpenMP was first published, the typical use case was for relatively heavyweight threads of computation taking seconds each.  Since then processors have got faster and implementations have got better, I don't think you'll get a good answer to your question without benchmarking.  And you're going to have to benchmark anyway, whatever you learn from SO, so stop wasting time and get coding.

You might be persuaded that OpenMP is not useful: but you won't quite trust the answer wrt your own requirements.

You might be persuaded that OpenMP is useful: but you won't quite trust the answer wrt your own requirements.

You might get a lot of conflicting anecdotal evidence: but you won't quite trust the answer wrt your own requirements.

Get benchmarking.  And let us know how you get on, SO is far too long on anecdotes (such as the trash I'm writing), far too short on hard data.

PS Don't lose your benchmark codes.  Revise them and rerun them as your experience develops and as your hardware, systems software and applications software change.  Of one thing I am convinced without data: the answer to your question is a moving target.

Comment: Well I kind of figured someone else might have already done benchmarking, and could share the results or better yet their benchmarking code so I can test without re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Sure I've benchmarked my codes on OpenMP, but I don't think the results would be any use to you.  My programs run for hours, so I'm not really interested, and haven't got good benchmarks for, figuring out the minimum sizes for OpenMP.

Comment: Hopefully someone else di try OpenMP in a gaming (or similar) context. All my previous work with OpenMP (which I think is great) was also processing large datasets. If it did scale to small tasks due to thread caching, it would be a really cool way to get some cheap optimization.